# How to dynamically populate a google stacked bar chart from an array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, google-visualization

I would like to use a google stacked bar chart.
Manually it would be just like that.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'A', 'B', 'C', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['2011', 2, 1, 1, ''],
        ['2012', 1, 0, 0, ''],
        ['2013', 0, 0, 1, ''],
        ['2014', 1, 1, 1, ''],
        ['2015', 1, 0, 0, '']
  ]);

      var options = {
      bar: { groupWidth: '64%' },
      chartArea: {width:'78%',height:'86%'},
      forceIFrame: 'true',
          isStacked: true,
      legend: {position: 'none'},
          titlePosition: 'none',
      vAxis: {title: 'Technological Fields'}
      };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('technological-fields'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

But the values of 'var data' should come from an array that is generated after a data bank query.
The original array (from the data bank) is like the following:

```
$limitedArray = array(
      array('A', 'B', 'G', 'D', 1, 'A', '2011-01-01'),
      array('K', 'L', 'M', 'O', 3, 'C', '2013-03-03'),
      array('K', 'L', 'M', 'O', 3, 'C', '2014-03-03'),
      array('P', 'P', 'S', 'T', 4, 'A', '2011-04-04'),
      array('A', 'B', 'G', 'D', 1, 'A', '2012-01-01'),
      array('E', 'Z', 'H', 'I', 2, 'B', '2011-02-02'),
      array('K', 'L', 'M', 'O', 3, 'C', '2011-03-03'),
      array('P', 'P', 'S', 'T', 4, 'A', '2014-04-04'),
      array('P', 'P', 'S', 'T', 4, 'B', '2014-04-04'),
      array('A', 'B', 'G', 'I', 1, 'A', '2015-05-05')
);
```

Then I try to get some data from this:

```
//CHART 02
$techArea = $limitedArray[$key][5];
$techAreaHeader[] = $techArea;
$prioDate = substr($limitedArray[$key][6],0,4);
$chartContent[] = "$prioDate".","."$techArea";

//Exclude duplicated rows of the header.
$header = array();
foreach ($techAreaHeader as &$value) {
        if (!isset($header[$value['0']]))
        $header[$value['0']] =& $value;
}
//Sort array from high to low.
asort($header);

//Transform array into string.
$strHeader = implode(', ', $header);
```

With that I get following result:

```
$header:
Array
(
    [A] => A
    [B] => B
    [C] => C
)

$strHeader (string):
A, B, C
```

This I could use in the first line of the 'var data' just like that:

```
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', <?php echo $strHeader ?>, { role: 'annotation' } ],
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach (probably not), but then I've got even bigger problems when I try to populate the rest of 'var data'.
I tried the following, but then I could not find any solution:

```
//Sort content array.
asort($chartContent);

//Count how many occurrences of a tech area in the same year.
$countedChartContent = array_count_values($chartContent);

$chart02 = implode(', ', array_map(function ($v, $k) { return $k.','.$v; }, $chart02, array_keys($chart02)));
```

With the following results:

```
$content (sorted):
Array
(
    [3] => 2011,A
    [0] => 2011,A
    [5] => 2011,B
    [6] => 2011,C
    [4] => 2012,A
    [1] => 2013,C
    [7] => 2014,A
    [8] => 2014,B
    [2] => 2014,C
    [9] => 2015,A
)

$countedChartContent:
Array
(
    [2011,A] => 2
    [2011,B] => 1
    [2011,C] => 1
    [2012,A] => 1
    [2013,C] => 1
    [2014,A] => 1
    [2014,B] => 1
    [2014,C] => 1
    [2015,A] => 1
)
```

Yeah! I'm stucked :-\
Did research, but could not go any further.
Anybody has a better idea how I can populate this 'var data' dynamically from my original array?
Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Build it to match then [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it.. `...arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($limitedArray); ?>);`

Comment: Thank you, @Loz-Cherone-ツ, but I have no idea how I can do this. Could you please show me?

Answer (score 0):

Build a PHP array that matches the expected JSON the chart requires, then use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to pass it as a JS object to the chart.

From:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'A', 'B', 'C', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['2011', 2, 1, 1, ''],
    ['2012', 1, 0, 0, ''],
    ['2013', 0, 0, 1, ''],
    ['2014', 1, 1, 1, ''],
    ['2015', 1, 0, 0, '']
]);
```

To:

```
$array = array(
    array('Year', 'A', 'B', 'C', array('role' => 'annotation')),
    array('2011', 2, 1, 1, ''),
    array('2012', 1, 0, 0, ''),
    array('2013', 0, 0, 1, ''),
    array('2014', 1, 1, 1, ''),
    array('2015', 1, 0, 0, ''),
);
```

For example.

```
<?php 
$array = array(
    array('Year', 'A', 'B', 'C', array('role' => 'annotation')),
    array('2011', 2, 1, 1, ''),
    array('2012', 1, 0, 0, ''),
    array('2013', 0, 0, 1, ''),
    array('2014', 1, 1, 1, ''),
    array('2015', 1, 0, 0, ''),
);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>);

        var options = {
            bar: { groupWidth: '64%' },
            chartArea: {width:'78%',height:'86%'},
            forceIFrame: 'true',
            isStacked: true,
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            titlePosition: 'none',
            vAxis: {title: 'Technological Fields'}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('technological-fields'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

<div id="technological-fields"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The problem with this is that I have no influence in the original array I receive from the data bank query. It can be always something different and your approach seems to be so manually as mine. Or do I see it wrong?

For example the values 2,1,1,0 etc are how many times the heads (A, B, C, etc) occur in the year. (That's because I tried something with array_count_values($chartContent), but unfortunatelly without success.

Comment: Yeah its a static example...your have to manipulate the original array then to suit what is expected, just do a foreach() and build what you want from the database result into a new array.